# What int values are relevant for exit() in C?

Tags: c, exit

On [TutorialsPoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_exit.htm), exit is passed the value `0`, while people often pass it `1`. I've even seen `exit(3);`

**What do the different values mean?**

Comment: I'm guessing that the `exit(3)` you see is actually a mention of the manual page, `exit()` being in section 3 (library functions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By convention, a program that exits successfully calls `exit` (or returns from `main`) with a value of 0.  Shell programs (most programs, actually) will look for this to determine if a program ran successfully or not.

Any other value is considered an abnormal exit.  What each of those values mean is defined by the program in question.

On Unix and similar systems, only the lower 8 bits of the exit value are used as the exit code of the program and are returned to the parent process on a call to `wait`.  Calling `exit(n)` is equivalent to calling `exit(n & 0xff)`

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit):

> The  `exit()` function causes normal process termination and the value
>   of `status & 0377` is returned to the parent (see `wait`(2)).

Comment: `Also, only the lower 8 bits of the exit value are used as the exit code of the program. Calling exit(n) is equivalent to calling exit(n & 0xff)` no, it's not correct on Windows, which return the whole 32 bits

Comment: And it's not only shell programs that use the exit status; `make` is an obvious non-shell example.  Arguably, any program that `wait`s for the exit status of a process should make use of that status (well, apart from `init` reaping orphans, of course).

Answer (score 9):

The only *portable* values to pass to `exit` are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. The latter two are macros defined in `<stdlib.h>`, the same header that declares the `exit` function.

Both `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` conventionally indicate that the program succeeded. `EXIT_FAILURE` indicates that it failed somehow. (`EXIT_SUCCESS` is almost certainly defined as `0`.)

For UNIX-like systems, `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined as `1`, and `exit(1)` is also common (though a bit less portable). Some operating systems might use a different convention; for example OpenVMS uses even values for failure and odd values for success, with some special-case code to map `exit(0)` to a failure status.

Other values may be used by some programs to indicate different kinds of failure. For example, the `grep` command uses `0` if a match was found, `1` if no match was found, and `2` if some other error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
   exit(0);
}
```

is the same as

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

The return values are basically error codes:

- `0` (or macro `EXIT_SUCCESS` defined in `"stdlib.h"`) means successful program termination
- `1` (or macro `EXIT_FAILURE` defined in `"stdlib.h"`) means program termination because of failure

Other error codes are also possible, but they are system dependent thus not part of the C standard, i.e. they are not portable.

Answer (score 2):

Exit values are program dependent. The biggest consideration is probably that most (all?) shells consider a return value of zero to mean success. Any other value indicates failure.

Comment: `grep -c` prints the number of matches to standard output. Its exit status is zero (successful) if there were matches, and its exit status is non-zero (unsuccessful) if there were no matches.

Comment: [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) returns the number of chosen value when finish successfully. But yes to the shells they indicate a failure when using in `&&`, `&`, `||`... operators